# Installing odbcins1debian2, broken dependency on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to install odbcinst1debian2 on Ubuntu 20.04 but it appears there is a missing dependency, "multiarch-support":

```
$ sudo apt-get install odbcinst1debian2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 odbcinst1debian2 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Running `sudo apt-get install -f` afterwards doesn't resolve the issue.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Since this package requires multiarch-support, I tried installing that directly, which didn't help either:

```
$ sudo apt-get install multiarch-support
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package multiarch-support is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'multiarch-support' has no installation candidate
```

How should this package and unixodbc-dev which depends upon it be installed?

```
$ sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
                Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

---

I had run `apt-get update`, it's the first thing I run on a new install.

```
$ sudo apt-get install odbcinst1debian2 
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation 
or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet
been created or been moved out of Incoming.
[Stuff deleted] 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: odbcinst1debian2 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 


$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 
Release: 20.04 Codename: focal

$ apt-cache policy odbcinst1debian2 
odbcinst1debian2: 
Installed: (none) 
Candidate: 2.3.7 
Version table: 
  2.3.7 500 
    500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic/main amd64 Packages 
  2.3.6-0.1build1 500 
    500 http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Did you forgot to run `sudo apt-get update`? What is the output of `lsb_release -a` and `apt-cache policy odbcinst1debian2`?

Comment: I had run `apt-get update`, it's the first thing I run on a new install.

```$ sudo apt-get install odbcinst1debian2
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
[Stuff deleted]
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 odbcinst1debian2 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: ```$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
```

Comment: ```$ apt-cache policy odbcinst1debian2
odbcinst1debian2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.3.7
  Version table:
     2.3.7 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic/main amd64 Packages
     2.3.6-0.1build1 500
        500 http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You can follow the below answer, optionally you have to decide about removing `packages.microsoft.com` repository from the system.

Answer (score 16):

This problems looks like you forgot to run `sudo apt-get update` before installing `odbcinst1debian2`. On *focal* this package [does not depend](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/odbcinst1debian2) on `multiarch-support`.

---

By the way [`multiarch-support`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/multiarch-support) may be installed manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
```

Comment: ```odbcinst1debian2 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable``` - it is a predepends, not a depends; packages.ubuntu.com is not showing the full set of dependencies - pre-depends is somewhat new. https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html

edit: I missed the packages.microsoft.com policy issue bringing in a poor dependency; I don't know if packages,ubuntu.com shows pre-dependencies correctly or not ;).

Comment: Update to the multiarch-support file: wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb

Comment: not sure if it's a typo, or the file got removed, but the right link to multiarch-support seems to be http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb

Comment: The path is changed to http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb

Comment: i can confirm that as of 04/27/2022, we need to use the new link 
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb to download this lib

Answer (score 11):

I had to `sudo apt-get install unixodbc` **before** adding Microsoft's source list, per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63187951/21115).

Answer (score 5):

As explained in comments and other answers, the issue comes from Microsoft advertising a more recent version of the packages.

However you may keep the Microsoft repository and set up a policy for it with a lower priority in `/etc/apt/preferences` :

```
Package: *
Pin: origin "packages.microsoft.com"
Pin-Priority: 1
```

Then use `apt-get update` and retry upgrading.

Comment: That's a great answer, which solved the same issue for me.

Comment: Underrated answer. Fix my issue immediately.